# How to make WIX installer adapt to the version of Windows Installer available - like the Hyperlink control

Tags: hyperlink, wix, windows-installer, conditional-statements, feature-detection

Windows Installer 5 added support for the Hyperlink control which I would like to utilize if available. I cannot set a dependency towards Windows Installer 5 (doesn't support WinXP), but I would like my installer to be able to utilize the hyperlink control if Windows Installer 5 is available when running the installer.

How do you manage to do this? Conditional imports of fragment files based on the [versionMsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372493%28VS.85%29.aspx) property? A [Google code search](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=versionMsi+file%3a.wxs&sbtn=Search) or [regular Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=versionMsi+filetype%3awxs) didn't reveal many samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to read this article:

[Careful with that Hyperlink (on your MSI dialog)](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/careful-with-that-hyperlink-on-your-msi-dialog/index.htm)

The summary is you create two nearly idential dialogs and create mutually exclusive control events to drive which one gets displayed based on your MSI version.

Comment: Adding a bit to this, you don't want conditional fragment imports (build-time) unless you want to make a panoply of .msi files. Instead you want conditions inside the one .msi you create which key off the VersionMsi property at run-time. In this case, as Chris says, it'd be in the dialog control events to select one of two dialogs.

Comment: Any pointers on how I would do this with WIX? Could I embed both dialogs within the same WXS file without risking an error during runtime since the dialog wont be used when the versionMsi is lower than 5.0?

Comment: @tronda, where you put the dialogs in your WXS files does not matter much.  The important piece is that you have a condition on your `Publish` tags which prevent the dialog with the hyperlink appearing unless the `VersionMsi` property is high enough.

Comment: Sorry, I only use WiX UI when I need Minimal with no customizations.  When I need heavy UI lifting I use InstallShield.

Comment: tronda did uncover a caveat to this solution [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411462/conditional-choose-between-two-exit-dialog-when-using-wixs-installdir-ui-extens) as the Exit dialog is a special case.

Comment: You could use Dynamic UI to inject the hyperlink control only when it's supported. http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/07/dynamic-windows-installer-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using [WIX Installer](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) and used this code. Wix is a free open source tool and is same like the costly other tools. I used this code for hyperlink and it works perfect

```
        <Control Id="MyHyperlinkControl1" Height="20" Width="100" Type="Hyperlink" X="5" Y="105">
          <Text><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a>]]></Text>
        </Control>
```

Comment: I cannot see how you address the main issue which is how to handle installers when the MSI version doesn't support Hyperlinks.