# Conditional choose between two exit dialog when using WIX's InstallDir UI extension

Tags: wix, windows-installer, conditional-statements, wix3.5, wix-extension

I would like to have two different exit dialogs based on the version of the VersionMsi property in order to utilize the hyperlink control for the exit dialog. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016620).

I'm using a customized version of WIX's InstallDir_UI extension for my install process. Since I would like to optionally support the hyperlink control if available, I have created two different dialogs:

```
<Dialog Id="NonHyperlinkExit" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.ExitDialog_Title)">
    <Control Id="Finish" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIFinish)" />
    ...
    <Control Id="HowToLink" Type="Text" X="135" Y="175" Width="220" Height="10" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InfoUrl)" />
    ...
</Dialog>

<Dialog Id="HyperlinkExit" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.ExitDialog_Title)">
    <Control Id="Finish" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIFinish)" />
    ...
    <Control Id="HowToHyperLink" Type="Hyperlink" X="135" Y="175" Width="220" Height="10" Text="!(loc.InfoLink)" />
    ...
</Dialog>
```

I've then modified the UI publish statements to support those dialogs to something like this:

```
<Publish Dialog="NonHyperlinkExit" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="998"><![CDATA[VersionMsi < "5.0"]]></Publish>
<Publish Dialog="HyperlinkExit" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999"><![CDATA[VersionMsi >= "5.0"]]></Publish>
```

When running this, I get the following errors:

```
error LGHT0204: ICE20: Exit dialog/action not found in 'AdminUISequence' Sequence Table. 
error LGHT0204: ICE82: This action HyperlinkExit has duplicate sequence number -1 in the table InstallUISequence
```

So I've tried to modify the InstallUISequence instead, but with little help. Tried this:

```
<InstallUISequence>
    ...
    <Show Dialog="NonHyperlinkExit" Before="HyperlinkExit"><![CDATA[VersionMsi < "5.0"]]></Show>
    <Show Dialog="HyperlinkExit" OnExit="success"><![CDATA[VersionMsi >= "5.0"]]></Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```

But this only give me the following error:

```
error LGHT0177: The InstallUISequence table contains an action 'NonHyperlinkExit' that is scheduled to come before or after action 'HyperlinkExit', 
which is a special action which only occurs when the installer terminates.  
These special actions can be identified by their negative sequence numbers.  
Please schedule the action 'NonHyperlinkExit' to come before or after a different action.
```

Any ideas on how to create conditional exit dialogs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSI supports only one exit dialog per state (e.g., success). You could use a custom action instead that showed the the appropriate dialog.

Comment: Or you can conditionally show or hide controls in your dialog depending on `VersionMsi` property.

Comment: Possible to show some example WiX code for on how to do this?

Comment: How would you handle the "exit state"? A custom action which represent the end state? Other ways?

Comment: The custom action would check the MSI version and use MsiDoAction to show one dialog for <5.0 and another for >=5.0. Alexey's technique is worth trying out, but as I recall, MSI throws an error if it encounters unknown control types, regardless of whether they're visible/enabled.

Comment: I would love to see an example of this.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a custom action to dynamically inject controls onto a dialog only when it's supported.  See:

[Dynamic Windows Installer UI](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/07/dynamic-windows-installer-ui.html)